# React app build/deploy using github actions with secrets

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, webpack, github-actions

I am trying to accomplish build/deploy my react app that uses Firebase(for now only auth module) using github actions with secrets.
For local development I use .env file with webpack and dotenv-webpack library. On local machine all works fine. Dev server get environment varialbles from .env file and inject it. But after build in github actions and deploying package on firebase hosting page return me an error:

```
code: "auth/invalid-api-key"
message: "Your API key is invalid, please check you have copied it correctly."
```

After some investigation I got that environment variables aren't defined properly:

```
apiKey: undefined
authDomain: undefined
databaseURL: undefined
messagingSenderId: undefined
projectId: undefined
storageBucket: undefined
```

The main question if i'm doing variable injection correct or maybe there is another way to do it?
My webpack config that I use in build:

**webpack.build.conf.js**

```
const { merge } = require('webpack-merge');
const baseWebpackConfig = require('./webpack.base.conf');

const buildWebpackConfig = merge(baseWebpackConfig, {
  //!!!
  //CAUTION Production config
  //!!!
  mode: 'production',
});

module.exports = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  resolve(buildWebpackConfig);
});
```

**webpack.base.conf.js**

```
const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const Dotenv = require('dotenv-webpack');

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/index.js',
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'build'),
    publicPath: '/',
    filename: 'bundle.min.js',
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.jsx'],
    alias: {
      '@constants': path.resolve(__dirname, './src/constants'),
      '@components': path.resolve(__dirname, './src/components'),
      '@utils': path.resolve(__dirname, './src/utils'),
      '@styles': path.resolve(__dirname, './src/style'),
    },
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: ['babel-loader', 'eslint-loader'],
      },
      {
        test: /\.less$/,
        use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader', 'less-loader'],
      },
    ],
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: path.resolve('./index.html'),
    }),
    new Dotenv(),
  ],
};
```

File that get variables from .env file:

```
//Firebase config
export const FB_API_KEY = process.env.REACT_APP_API_FB_KEY;
export const FB_AUTH_DOMAIN = process.env.REACT_APP_FB_AUTH_DOMAIN;
export const FB_DATABASE_URL = process.env.REACT_APP_FB_DATABASE_URL;
export const FB_PROJECT_ID = process.env.REACT_APP_FB_PROJECT_ID;
export const FB_STORAGE_BUCKET = process.env.REACT_APP_STORAGE_BUCKET;
export const FB_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID = process.env.REACT_APP_FB_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID;
```

Pipeline file:

```
name: Firebase Deploy
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - master
jobs:
  build:
    name: Build
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout Repo
        uses: actions/checkout@master
        env:
          REACT_APP_API_FB_KEY: ${{ secrets.REACT_APP_API_FB_KEY }}
          REACT_APP_FB_AUTH_DOMAIN: ${{ secrets.REACT_APP_FB_AUTH_DOMAIN }}
          REACT_APP_FB_DATABASE_URL: ${{ secrets.REACT_APP_FB_DATABASE_URL }}
          REACT_APP_FB_PROJECT_ID: ${{ secrets.FB_PROJECT_ID }}
          REACT_APP_FB_STORAGE_BUCKET: ${{ secrets.FB_STORAGE_BUCKET }}
          REACT_APP_FB_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID: ${{ secrets.FB_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID }}
      - name: Variable to dotenv
          uses: CallePuzzle/envvar-to-dotenv-action@0.1.0
          with:
            variableNamesByFilter: ^REACT_(APP.*)
      - name: Install Dependencies
        run: npm install
      - name: Build
        run: npm run build
      - name: Archive Production Artifact
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@master
        with:
          name: build
          path: build
  deploy:
    name: Deploy
    needs: build
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout Repo
        uses: actions/checkout@master
      - name: Download Artifact
        uses: actions/download-artifact@master
        with:
          name: build
          path: build
      - name: Deploy to Firebase
        uses: w9jds/firebase-action@master
        with:
          args: deploy --only hosting
        env:
          FIREBASE_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.FIREBASE_TOKEN }}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found solution. The problem was in *Webpack* configuration. It seems that *Webpack* need to define environment variables at compile time. For that I used [webpack.DefinePlugin](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/define-plugin/)

**webpack.build.conf.js**

```
const { merge } = require('webpack-merge');
const baseWebpackConfig = require('./webpack.base.conf');
const webpack = require('webpack');

const buildWebpackConfig = merge(baseWebpackConfig, {
  //!!!
  //CAUTION Production config
  //!!!
  mode: 'production',
  plugins: [
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env': {
        REACT_APP_API_FB_KEY: JSON.stringify(process.env.REACT_APP_API_FB_KEY),
        REACT_APP_FB_AUTH_DOMAIN: JSON.stringify(process.env.REACT_APP_FB_AUTH_DOMAIN),
        REACT_APP_FB_DATABASE_URL: JSON.stringify(process.env.REACT_APP_FB_DATABASE_URL),
        REACT_APP_FB_PROJECT_ID: JSON.stringify(process.env.REACT_APP_FB_PROJECT_ID),
        REACT_APP_STORAGE_BUCKET: JSON.stringify(process.env.REACT_APP_STORAGE_BUCKET),
        REACT_APP_FB_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID: JSON.stringify(process.env.REACT_APP_FB_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID),
      },
    }),
  ],
});

module.exports = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  resolve(buildWebpackConfig);
});
```

And don't need to append .env file. Variables passed down perfectly in process.env:

```
name: Firebase Deploy
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - master
env:
  REACT_APP_API_FB_KEY: ${{ secrets.REACT_APP_API_FB_KEY }}
  REACT_APP_FB_AUTH_DOMAIN: ${{ secrets.REACT_APP_FB_AUTH_DOMAIN }}
  REACT_APP_FB_DATABASE_URL: ${{ secrets.REACT_APP_FB_DATABASE_URL }}
  REACT_APP_FB_PROJECT_ID: ${{ secrets.FB_PROJECT_ID }}
  REACT_APP_FB_STORAGE_BUCKET: ${{ secrets.FB_STORAGE_BUCKET }}
  REACT_APP_FB_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID: ${{ secrets.FB_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID }}
jobs:
  build:
    name: Build
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Debug Action
        uses: hmarr/debug-action@v1.0.0
      - name: Checkout Repo
        uses: actions/checkout@master
      - name: Install Dependencies
        run: npm install
      - name: Build
        run: npm run build
      - name: Archive Production Artifact
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@master
        with:
          name: build
          path: build
  deploy:
    name: Deploy
    needs: build
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout Repo
        uses: actions/checkout@master
      - name: Download Artifact
        uses: actions/download-artifact@master
        with:
          name: build
          path: build
      - name: Deploy to Firebase
        uses: w9jds/firebase-action@master
        with:
          args: deploy --only hosting
        env:
          FIREBASE_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.FIREBASE_TOKEN }}
```

Thanks you a lot.

Answer (score 1):

```
name: Firebase Deploy
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - master

env:
  REACT_APP_API_FB_KEY: ${{ secrets.REACT_APP_API_FB_KEY }}
  REACT_APP_FB_AUTH_DOMAIN: ${{ secrets.REACT_APP_FB_AUTH_DOMAIN }}
  REACT_APP_FB_DATABASE_URL: ${{ secrets.REACT_APP_FB_DATABASE_URL }}
  REACT_APP_FB_PROJECT_ID: ${{ secrets.FB_PROJECT_ID }}
  REACT_APP_FB_STORAGE_BUCKET: ${{ secrets.FB_STORAGE_BUCKET }}
  REACT_APP_FB_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID: ${{ secrets.FB_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID }}

obs:
  build:
    name: Build
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout Repo
        uses: actions/checkout@master
...
```

How about moving `env` section to the top level? currently `env` is only affected with checkout step and checkout is irrelevant since injecting env into the source is in the build phase.

or you may pass the env in the build step.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I tried that too. And it not working in my case. Right now I tried to add blank .env file and append it with variables. But that didn't work too.

Comment: I thought you use create-react-app since you use `REACT_APP_` prefix in envs. but it seems like you have webpack config by yourself. is this correct?
1. if I'm correct, usually we write value in `.env` directly and use `process.env.REACT_APP_API_FB_KEY` in the source code. 2. in some case I use  webpack.DefinePlugin to pass env to the source code.

Comment: Yep, I am using .env file for dev. With dotenv-webpack plugin. But for production I want to use github secrets so I don't need to store valuable keys in rep.