# Is there a way to auto-pull environmental variables like a .env file when sharing a repository amongst team members?

Tags: github, environment-variables, github-actions, github-api, development-environment

So….if you want to have environmental variables, you’ll create the .env file right? Well…what if you want to share a repo with team members? Do they have to each manually create a .env file when working on the repository locally or is there a better solution than that? I’m just trying to think of the security behind not allowing everyone to have access to the private strings in a .env file but be able to use the repo as if there was a .env file.

I’m hosting my code in GitHub for reference. Is this a GitHub actions thing or is there another solution? Any help would earn my eternal gratitude in this dire time, lol

There is this Stack Overflow thread that is similar, but I don't want the environmental variables for deployment, just for team-members to do a git-pull and get the repository to work locally without needing to custom-create the .env file and add in the environmental variable strings: [React app build/deploy using github actions with secrets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63398836/react-app-build-deploy-using-github-actions-with-secrets)

Comment: I think you just need a hook to grab the `.env` from s3 or some place. it would be applicable for both local and CI.

Comment: You can split your environment variables into multiple files. Some would contain secret values (and would not be committed) and some would contain simple defaults that depend on the environment. Here's the docs: https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables/#what-other-env-files-can-be-used